# Should I pass my APIKEY in every request I do with Retrofit?

Tags: retrofit2, rx-java2, api-key

I'd like to know the best way to put my APIKEY in all my REST requests withtout having to add it in parameters of the request.

For now I just have a couple of calls, but I'm trying to see further.

```
@GET(".")
fun getSearch(@Query("s") text: String, @Query("apikey") APIKEY: String) : Observable<ResponseSearch>
```

I was wondering if there was a way not to have the APIKEY in variables of every call

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can, but the better solution is to use [Okhttp Interceptors](https://square.github.io/okhttp/interceptors/)

Here's an example:

```
class TokenInterceptor(private val preferencesStorage: SharedPreferencesStorage) : Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        var original = chain.request()
        val token = preferencesStorage.getAccessToken()
        val url = original.url().newBuilder().addQueryParameter("apikey", token).build()
        original = original.newBuilder().url(url).build()
        return chain.proceed(original)
    }
}
```

You should also add TokenInterceptor to your Okhttp client builder

```
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(TokenInterceptor(SharedPreferencesStorage()))
            .build()
```

Comment: The API I'm calling doesn't allow the key to be in header. I've just tried with Postman

Comment: You can do that with Interceptors as well, I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

More "modern" way to achieve it

```kotlin
private fun apiKeyAsQuery(chain: Interceptor.Chain) = chain.proceed(
        chain.request()
            .newBuilder()
            .url(chain.request().url.newBuilder().addQueryParameter("api-key", ApiKey).build())
            .build()
    )

private fun apiKeyAsHeader(it: Interceptor.Chain) = it.proceed(
    it.request()
        .newBuilder()
        .addHeader("api-key", ApiKey)
        .build()
)

...
.client(
    OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor { apiKeyAsQuery(it) }
        // Or
        .addInterceptor { apiKeyAsHeader(it) }
        .build()
)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to have a middleware for your requests, where all queries passed through it, and there you will have a single point of adding the APIkey, also i would prefer it to add it to the header instead of query parameters